# Drawing different objects on leaflet map with custom controls

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I would like to draw different type of objects on a leaflet map with leaflet-geoman. I have a geojson layer not editable (agricol parcels) on overlay pane and I want to choose in a combobox (or buttons nethermind) the type of object to draw.
It can be markers (for trees for example) or polyline (hedge...) or polygone (forest...) with different style (color, marker, tooltip...) : a forest is green, a tree with some icon, a hedge is brown, a forest is green fill....
Just after the end of drawing, I would like to show a popup to fill some information like the name of the object for example.
I would like to put all these drawings in a layer that can be shown/hide with the pane control.
I can have different layers according to the type of objects.
At least, I would like to get all drawn objects (with extra informations...) and save it in geojson.
Do you have an example for doing such thing ? I still didn't found anything.
Thank's

Guen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different draw shapes to give them different color: [customcontrols.js](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman/blob/59e281464308ea1e2f5fad3e4355e9ea01cca13d/demo/customcontrols.js#L48):

```
map.pm.Toolbar.copyDrawControl('Rectangle', {
  name: 'RectangleCopy',
  block: 'custom',
  title: 'Display text on hover button',
  actions: _actions,
});
map.pm.Draw.RectangleCopy.setPathOptions({ color: 'green' });
```

Then check on the `pm:create` listener which shape is created and then add a popup to it:

```
map.on('pm:create',(e)=>{
  if(e.shape === 'RectangleCopy'){
     e.layer.bindPopup('Treee').openPopup();
  }
});
```

To add a layers to a FeatureGroup you can use `map.pm.setGlobalOptions({layerGroup: YOUR_GROUP});`

And to get all drawn layers you can call `map.pm.getGeomanDrawLayers(true).toGeoJSON()` or because you have your own group: `YOUR_GROUP.toGeoJSON()`

Comment: And I continue... How I can get the type of the shape and a unique valeur created when I finish the draw with myLayer.toGeaoJSON() ? Beacause I need to save this informations with the geom in the database... Thank's

Comment: I found e.marker._leaflet_id to get unique id on pm:create but how I can have this id in the export toGeoJSON() ?

Comment: and I found how to pass custom informations on options but not to get this info in properties geoJson. I can read all the myLayer.pm._layers and get all these info but I must transform _latlng to geojson... is there a function for that in geoman ?

Comment: Don't use `_leaflet_id` as your unique id, because when you reload the map the leaflet_id will start again by zero. And then you have your id twice. You need to generate a custom id by your self or on the database by incementing the line id `1,2,3,4,...`.

Comment: Don't use `myLayer.pm._layers` for this `myLayer.getLayers()` is existing. But I suggest you following: `map.pm.getGeomanDrawLayers().forEach((layer)=>{console.log(layer.toGeoJOSN())});`. To get the options of each layer you need to create you own code. You can read the options with `layer.options` and then add it to the properties of the geoJosn of the layer `... .properties = layer.options`

Comment: ok thank's. it works with myLayer.getLayers() and then add properties with layer.option.